# How can I use php file as an array, instead of class in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

This is my file with array for seeding DataBase:

```
<?php

namespace App\MyFolder;

return [
  [
    'name' => 'manufacturing firm',
    'values' => [
        'test1',
        'test 2',
        'test 3',
    ],
  ],
];
```

Then I try to use it inside my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\MyFolder;

class UserController extends Controller
{
   public function index() {

     //.... error class not found  
     return MyFolder;
   }

}
```

How can I use arrays, but non-class based files?

> Error: Undefined constant **'App\MyFolder'**

Comment: There is no class, just a namespaced PHP file. Include the file. `return require 'app\MyFolder.php' `

Comment: Please show the COMPLETE error message and the code. I dont think your problem is what you think it is

Comment: @RiggsFolly already updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the file like this:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
   public function index()
   {
     return File::getRequire(base_path().'/app/MyFolder/yourfile.php'); // path to your file
   }

}
```